# Public frameworks in an iOS app

Tags: ios, frameworks

Lets say: App1 and App2 are two different apps from the same developer which depends on a common dynamic framework: Framework1. In this scenario, if a user installs both App1 and App2, there will be two different versions of Framework1 installed on iOS with default settings. 
Is there any setting that we can use, so we can create Framework1 such that it can be shared with app1 and app2 on a device that has both apps- app1 and app2 installed?

Answer (score 1):

No, iOS sandboxing would prevent this.

In order to use your Framework1, the framework would need to be located in the app bundle. Apps are prevented from accessing other app bundles, even if they're from the same developer. App1 and App2 can share data, via app group settings, but not code (including frameworks).

If you were talking about App1 and an app extension (like a today extension) it would be different. App extensions are shipped as part of an app's bundle, so it's possible to have them access the same copy of a framework as the app they're bundled with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Does this mean that the versioning -minor version, major version settings that we get on a dynamic framework are useless on an iOS project as app & app extensions are always shared to app store in a single ipa?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in that comment, but it seems to be completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: As far as I understand, we have versioning on frameworks- minor and major versions (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/VersionInformation.html) to manage support with other apps that share the framework. Since sharing of frameworks in iOS is restricted due to sandboxing, it seems versioning is just a number. Does it seem correct?

Comment: If you are going to reuse your framework for your other apps or share/publish, then framework-version will be very helpful.  If you are going to use one workspace with projects to develop both your framework and app(s), then versioning is not necessary needed since any change to framework-project Xcode will rebuild the project and make all required update.

Comment: This whole discussion is completely irrelevant to the question at the top of this page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that this is possible. Every app have own Framework and own access to it. It can't be shared

Answer (score 0):

As `@Tom Harrington` cited `Embedded Frameworks` are located within an app’s Bundle and not shared between apps, each app has its own copy. 
Only Apple can create `System Frameworks` witch are stored at the system-level and are available to all apps.